# Spring MVC - JDBCTemplate - Transactional

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc, transactions

I am trying SPRING MVC with JDBCTemplate with transactional save. When it is transactional, when there is any error while saving in database, I am expecting it to rollback all database operations. Here I have considered 2 tables and saving data in both tables in a single method which has annotation @Transactional. Purposefully I was sending  more text than the size declared in db for a field to see whether first table data is getting rolled back, but it saves in the first table (not getting rolled back). Please help me to solve the issue.

### Beans.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

                    <!-- Initialization for TransactionManager -->  
                   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">  
                  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>       
               </bean>  

               <!-- Initialization for data source -->
               <bean id="dataSource" 
                  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
                  <property name="username" value="root"/>
                      <property name="password" value="root"/>
               </bean>

               <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
               <bean id="studentJDBCTemplate" class="com.springjdbctemplate.StudentJDBCTemplate">
                  <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
               </bean>

            </beans>
```

### StdentJDBCTemplate:

```
    public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudentDAO {

        private DataSource dataSource;
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @Override
        public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
            this.dataSource = ds;
            this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
        }

        @Transactional
        @Override
        public void create(String name, Integer age, int id, String address) {
            String SQL = "insert into springstudent (name, age, id) values (?, ?, ?)";
                jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, name, age, id);
            System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age + " id = " + id);

            SQL = "insert into springaddress (name, address) values (?, ?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, name, address);
            System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " address = " + address);

        }

        @Override
        public Student getStudent(Integer id) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Student> listStudents() {
            String SQL = "select * from springstudent";
            List<Student> students = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new StudentMapper1());
            return students;
        }
```

### web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>SpringSampleApplications</display-name>

       <servlet>
            <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

### MainApp:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext context = 
                     new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

              StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate = (StudentJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("studentJDBCTemplate");

            System.out.println("------Records Creation--------" );
              studentJDBCTemplate.create("Zara", 11, 1, "addr1");
              studentJDBCTemplate.create("Nuha", 2, 2, "addr2");
              studentJDBCTemplate.create("Ayan", 15, 3, "addr3addr1addr1");

              System.out.println("------Listing Multiple Records--------" );
              List<Student> students = studentJDBCTemplate.listStudents();
              for (Student record : students) {
                 System.out.print("ID : " + record.getId() );
                 System.out.print(", Name : " + record.getName() );
                 System.out.println(", Age : " + record.getAge());
              }
```

Please help me what am I missing.. thankssss

Comment: Check what do you use javax.transaction.Transactional or org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional.

Comment: @Dmytro, I am using import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional; in my code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dataSource is not setup for "autoCommit=true".

And you need to add something like this to your Beans.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer -- but the driver im using is "         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource". with this when I try defaultAutoCommit property, it throws an error that the property is not supported. I tried using in another way -- try {
   this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } this doesnt throw any error but first table data was getting saved :(

Comment: I guess the DriverManagerDataSource does defaultAutoCommit=false by itself. But I have edited my answer - you need to enable annotational transactions.

Comment: with annotation-driven -- I am getting error when I run the code  ERROR:  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;)       AND If I remove the line annotation-driven, code is working (but transactional is not acheivable).

Comment: Is that the complete stacktrace?

Comment: I could not paste whole trace here..  Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition;
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.ja)

Comment: I cant figure this one out, but my guess is that either you have conflicting library versions or perhaps some library is missing. I believe you need e.g. cglib and spring-aop.